# how to convert new line and html code in htmlspecialchars in php

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

here is my string

```
hello


world



<textarea>hello world</textarea>
```

how can I convert this string

```
hello

&nbsp;

world

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

&lt;textarea&gt;hello world&lt;/textarea&gt;
```

in php. Any one help please... I am try htmlspecialchars(); function but that doesn't work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

please read more on php ..Maybe this can help you https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/default.asp

```
<?php

    echo "hello";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "world";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<input type = 'textare' value = 'hello world'>";
    ?>
```